# sharepoint online csom powershell $w.RequestAccessEmail does not return value

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, csom

I am creating a script to check if the site has Request Access Enabled. this is a snippet of my script:

```
 foreach($w in $web.Webs)
{
      #$w.RequestAccessEmail = "admin@comp.onmicrosoft.com"
      Write-Host $w.RequestAccessEmail
}
```

it is not returning any value even though it is enabled, however, it does print if i set a value to it which i dont want to do. why is it not returning any value?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to load the `RequestAccessEmail` property of the web. Using C# you can do this very easily using a lambda expression:

```
var web = ctx.Web; 
ctx.Load(web, w => w.Fields.Include(f => f.RequestAccessEmail)); 
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

The following article describes how you can achieve the same functionality as above using PowerShell - https://www.itunity.com/article/loading-specific-values-lambda-expressions-sharepoint-csom-api-windows-powershell-1249